# math tools and cleveref gives no equation number

Tags: cleveref, mathtools

Using the following

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[tbtags]{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{%
    showonlyrefs = true
    ,showmanualtags = true
    }
\usepackage{varioref}   
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{equation}\label{eq:distribution}
    \langle T_{ f } , \phi \rangle := \int f( t) \phi( t ) dt
\end{equation}
%
Equation~\eqref{eq:distribution}
%
\end{document}
```

I get no equation number, just  `Equation (1)`. If I comment out \mathtoolset and if I use `\cref` or `\vref` it is working. If I comment out `\usepackage{cleveref}` and using `\eqref` it is working, too.

Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: Unrelated to what you ask for: You might want to use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` for the pairing. One can read about good ways to do this in the mathtools manual.

Comment: It is (now) clearly stated in the `mathtools` manual that `showonlyrefs` only affect `\eqref`, You probably need to have `\cref` also execute `\refeq` on the label.

Comment: @mickep Your are right, but this will not change anything

Comment: @daleif As I wrote: commenting out `\usepackage{cleveref}` and using` \eqref ` everything is ok. With `\usepackage{cleveref}` and '\eqref'  it is not working

Comment: I don't use `'cleverref` so no idea

Comment: As far as I can gather `cleverref` and the `showonlyrefs` feature are not compatible at all.

Comment: @daleif: This is also mentioned in the users guide which I recognized now. Also the autonomy-package is not working properly. Good feature but useless in connection with cleveref.

Comment: As mentioned I never use cleveref in my own projects, for me it is often too clever and I wanted something more low level, so my solution works directly on looking at the structure of the label key. Of course annoying when a theorem is changed to a lemma, but my editor has tools to update labels throughout a project.

Comment: @daleif Is your tool public available?

Comment: @Ulrich no, it uses the same idea as `fancyref` (I think it is). If you're referring to my editors tools? Then yes, that is just some of the reatures from auctex/reftex in Emacs

Comment: @daleif I am not using emacs, but TeXShop. Anyway, could you please send me a link the the emacs-macros?

Comment: No, it is a build in part of reftex